# How to use / not use 'Always'?

Tags: verbs, continuous-aspect

Recently I was informed that 'Always' can be used with continuous verbs but only if it is used on situations with bad implications, such as *teenagers are always causing trouble*. But what about these examples that aren't necessarily bad?

> 1. He was always trying his best.
> 2. The lad was always taking care of the kids.
> 3. She is always giving things to the poor.
> 4. He is always thinking of you.

I restructured examples without using continuous verb.

> 1. He always tried his best.
> 2. The lad always took care of the kids.
> 3. She always gave things to the poor.
> 4. He always thought of you.

I believe there is no strict rule but I hope to get more feedback about this.

Comment: The first set of sentences seem to pose a question..."but then?" Like, He was always trying his best, but (then what happened...?) The lad was always taking care of the kids; but ....(then what happened?).  But in the second set of sentences, that tenor is reduced, if not 'nil'.  I think they sound better in the second set, unless the writer has some more things to tell.

Comment: All of these examples are fine. Among the continuous-verb examples, (1) and (4) are especially idiomatic. This rule you were told about negativity does not exist.

Comment: "He was always trying his best" implies that the outcome did not match the effort -- I assume he failed somehow. The conversation would probably include how he failed. "The lad was always taking care of the kids" is a somewhat unusual construction. It could mean 'The lad frequently took care of the kids those days' or 'The lad never stopped prioritizing the kids in that situation'. "She is always giving things to the poor" lets me know she is quite generous, and that it is her habit to give things to the poor. "He is always thinking of you." could mean a couple things, but sounds quite sweet.